# Modify the languageDefinitions.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

I need to add custom languages to the LanguageDefinitions.config file in the App_Config folder. I want to do this via a patch file that would get generated once I build and deploy.
I tried adding a languagedefinitions.config file in the app_config/include folder with the new languages, but the application breaks with the following error:
Object reference not set to instance of an object

[image]

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you post your languagedefinitions.config? What version of Sitecore is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LanguageDefinitions.config` file is just an extension of the normal `<sitecore>` node of the config. It is included in the config using the following in **sitecore.config** file:

```xml
<languageDefinitions>
  <sc.include file="/App_Config/LanguageDefinitions.config" />
</languageDefinitions>
```

This causes the file to be included in Sitecore config like all the files in /App_Config/Include folder. To add your own custom language definition, you can patch this config using regular Sitecore patching syntax, for example:

**/App_Config/Include/z.Custom/LanguageDefinition.Custom.config**

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
        <languageDefinitions>
            <languages>
                <language id="en" region="EU" codepage="65001" encoding="utf-8" charset="iso-8859-1" icon="flags/16x16/flag_eu.png"/>
            </languages>
        </languageDefinitions>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

You can check the patched config in `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`.

Comment: This is great! Thank you!